# If statement is showing double results

Tags: php

I am showing two types of listings. One is auction and second in buynow. I am storing the listing type in database as "type".
what i want that, when a listing type is auction then a hammer image (auction.png) should show and when a listing type is buynow then , should show.
But in my current code, Where a listing type is "auction", it is displaying the both auction.png and . Please guide

Here is my code

```
      <?php
        
            $SelectListings = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM seller_listings");
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($SelectListings)){
                
                $type = $row['type'];
                
                $imgName        = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE images_id='".$row['images_id']."'");
                $image          = mysqli_fetch_assoc($imgName);
        ?>
        
        <div class="col-md-3 cust-padd">
            <a href="">
                <div class="item-box">
                    <div class="item-img">
                        <img src="img/product-img8.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-price-card">
                    <?php
                    if($type=="auction"){ ?>
                    
                        <span>$2,500.00 <img src="img/auction.png"></span>
                    
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        
                    
                    <?php } ?>
                        <span>$2,500.00 <i class="fa fa-tag"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Your `else` block is empty. I think you meant to put the second `<span>` inside there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `<span>` is outside the conditions.

Change:

```
<?php } else { ?>
    

<?php } ?>
    <span>$2,500.00 <i class="fa fa-tag"></i></span>
```

To:

```
<?php } else { ?>
    
    <span>$2,500.00 <i class="fa fa-tag"></i></span>

<?php } ?>
```

Should fix it.